# Nateeza Aginity workbench - concatenating two columns in a join

Tags: sql

Hi All currently I have an issue where i have two take two columns in table A, combine them and compare in join against one column in table B. The two columns in table A are defined as characters(3) and Charters(5), while the column in table B is defined as varchar(600)

My existing query looks something like this but it is not working

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.CLIENT_NO, TRIM(A.BRANCH_NO)||TRIM(A.ACCT_NO) as 
ACCOUNT_NUMBER, B.ID1 from TABLEA A
LEFT JOIN TABLE B ON CONCAT(TRIM(A.BRANCH_NO), TRIM(A.ACCT_NO)) = B.ACCT_NUM
```

The above does not work, also i have tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.CLIENT_NO, TRIM(A.BRANCH_NO)||TRIM(A.ACCT_NO) as 
ACCOUNT_NUMBER, B.ID1 from TABLEA A
LEFT JOIN TABLE B ON TRIM(A.BRANCH_NO)+TRIM(A.ACCT_NO) = B.ACCT_NUM
```

I have also tried explicit type casting and that didnt work either

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.CLIENT_NO, TRIM(A.BRANCH_NO)||TRIM(A.ACCT_NO) as 
    ACCOUNT_NUMBER, B.ID1 from TABLEA A
    LEFT JOIN TABLE B ON CAST(TRIM(A.BRANCH_NO) AS VARCHAR(600))+CAST(TRIM(A.ACCT_NO)AS VARCHAR(600)) = B.ACCT_NUM
```

Can some one please as to what I am missing ? Or Am i just concatenating the two columns incorrectly. The error i keep getting is to use explicit cast error or function concat cannot be identified.

ANy help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which DBMS are you running this in? e.g. SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL...

Comment: Hey Christian, I am using Nateeza DBMS, i hope that answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Ok i think i figured this out, nateeza dbms works a little differently than i previously thought

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.CLIENT_NO, TRIM(A.BRANCH_NO)||TRIM(A.ACCT_NO) as 
ACCOUNT_NUMBER, B.ID1 from TABLEA A
LEFT JOIN TABLE B ON TRIM(A.BRANCH_NO) || TRIM(A.ACCT_NO) = B.ACCT_NUM
```

The above worked for me